# clipboardItems.types not containing all data

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste, webapi

I'm copying some text from a [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GxOpnn81-wa2GXXzlU8xru-jcH_joczLrXusLJ8QX6g/edit?usp=sharing) to the clipboard and inspecting its content.

I've tried inspecting it by using the `paste` event and by using the `clipboard` API.

When inspecting with the paste event, it exposes 3 items, but when using the clipboard API, only two items are available.

Here's my  code for  clipboard API, this only prints two items:

```
navigator.clipboard.read().then(clipboardItems => {
    for (const clipboardItem of clipboardItems) {

        for (const type of clipboardItem.types) {
            clipboardItem.getType(type).then(blob => blob.text())
                .then(console.log);
        }

    }
})
```

And here's my code  using the  paste  event. Three items  are  available.

```
target.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
let items = event.clipboardData.items
for(let  i of  items){
if(i.kind==='string'){
i.getAsString(console.log)
}
}
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically when using the paste event there's a  new item  of type `application/x-vnd.google-docs-document-slice-clip+wrapped`.  Why  doesn't it  come up when  using clipboard API?

[This tool](https://evercoder.github.io/clipboard-inspector/) might be helpful to inspect the  clipboard.